# Filter recordset based on datasheet filter

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I would like to apply the filter of a datasheet form to a recordset if the "FilterOn" property is true and make sure the record order is the same as well.
I tried this earlier but the code didn't run the event so there must be something wrong.

```
    Dim rsAll As DAO.Recordset
    Set rsAll = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("All Patient Info")
    if Forms("All Patient Info").FilterOn then
    rsAll.Filter = Forms("All Patient Info").Filter
    End if
```

Comment: If you're uncertain whether the code runs at all, set a breakpoint on the `Set rsAll` line, run the code, and see whether Access enters break mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter does nothing useful before you assign the recordset to another recordset:

```
Dim rsAll As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsFilter As DAO.Recordset
Set rsAll = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("All Patient Info")
If Forms("All Patient Info").FilterOn Then
    rsAll.Filter = Forms("All Patient Info").Filter
    Set rsFilter = rsAll.OpenRecordset()
End if
```

Then proceed with rsFilter.

Comment: @HansUp: That's right, it was missing. I've made the correction. Thanks.